# Is zero-copy only supported by Kafka on linux?

Tags: linux, performance, apache-kafka, zero-copy

I am currently studying Kafka and it says that one of its main features is that it uses zero-copy to improve performance in message transmission and reception between brokers and clients.

I understand that zero-copy is only provided in Linux, but does Kafka for Windows and Mac OS not provide zero-copy?

If it does not provide zero-copy, is there a significant difference in performance in message transmission between non-Linux-based Kafka and Linux-based Kafka?

Comment: AFAIK, the feature is available for UNIX machines (Mac included). JVM byte code doesn't have Mac-specific functions. But companies don't run hundreds of Mac machines just for server hardware. Kafka isn't thoroughly tested on windows, and has many failure conditions if you search though the project JIRA

Comment: @OneCricketeer , First, I would like to thank OneCricketeer for the kind and helpful answer. It has been very helpful.
Another question I have is, when looking at the introduction of Kafka by Twitter(https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/insights/2018/twitters-kafka-adoption-story), they mention the difference between their in-house message bus and Kafka, specifically mentioning Kafka's zero-copy feature. Would it be correct to assume that the in-house message bus used a combination of zero-copy and memory copy?

Comment: You'll have to find any engineers left at Twitter that can answer that